# write a new column in a file

Tags: c, printf, multiple-columns

I'm struggling with format of the output i'd like to have. the function below will take the input from another function and then write it down into a file. The input (x) is given every second, and for each input I need a new column to be output. This is what I want to output(different inputs marked as 1 and 2 etc...) The function posted shows only the format that I intend to have for one output, but that should increment for each input (The best I could do was to append the next column to the last line)

--

--

--

--

--

12 // for each input, output a new column like previous ones

```
void writeFile(int x){

  FILE *fptr;
  fptr=fopen("writertest.txt","w");
  if(fptr==NULL){
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
  }

  fprintf(fptr,"%s","-\n-\n-\n-\n-\n");
  fprintf(fptr, "%d", x);

  fclose(fptr);

}
```

Comment: You may consider save the end position of each line related to beginning of the file that you want to write and use [`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to change position.  Or if you have enough memory, you can save the data you want to write into an array and write it to the file at the end of your program.

Comment: seems not to work. The output I get is: one column and then just one line of the next one